# How to implement the copy constructor and overloaded equal operator for a BST in C++

Tags: c++, copy, operator-overloading, binary-search-tree

I need to implement a variety of functions for a BST using C++.  Two of these methods, the copy constructor and overloaded equal operator, I am confused on the exact logic of them and how to take that logic and actually turn it into code.

So far this is how I think the logic should work:

1. the copy constructor is called and uses the equal overload operator to set the copy tree equal to the local tree.
2. the equal overloaded method steps through visiting each node of the tree and copies the exact properties of each node so that the trees are the exact same, which should hopefully result in a deep copy.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
template <class DataType>
class BSTree
{
private:
    // You may NOT add any data members
    struct node;
    typedef node* nodePtr;

    struct node
    {
        DataType element;
        nodePtr right;
        nodePtr left;
    };
    int count;
    nodePtr root;
public:
    // Default constructor
    BSTree()
    {
        root = NULL;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    BSTree(const BSTree<DataType>& copyTree)
    {
        this = copyTree; //utilizes the overloaded = operator
    }

    // Equal overload
    const BSTree& operator =(const BSTree& rhs)
    {
        recursiveStepThrough(rhs, root);
    }

    void recursiveStepThrough(const BSTree& rhs, nodePtr curr) {
        if (curr != NULL) {
            if (curr->left != NULL) { recursiveStepThrough(rhs, curr->left); }
            nodePtr temp = new node;
            rhs->element = curr->element;
            rhs->right = curr->right;
            rhs->left = curr->left;
            if (curr->right != NULL) { recursiveStepThrough(rhs, curr->right); }
        }
    }
```

I am only given the private data members and the method headers.  I can create any new functions that I wish however I would like to keep it to what is provided to me by the instructor.  Any help on either the logic or the implementation would be of great help.

Comment: For the record: `const BSTree& operator =(const BSTree&)` is not the "equal" operator but the **assignment operator**. The correct, idiomatic return type would be `BSTree&` (without `const`). (This is done to allow chaining of assignments with non-const accesses which you would prohibit unnecessarily otherwise.) And, the assignment operator has to `return *this;` what is missing in your code. (There is also something, what I would consider as "equal" operator: `bool operator ==(const BSTree&) const` which can be overloaded as well. Hence, my nit-picking...)

Comment: Assignment and equality are the same in the mathematical sense. Pure functional languages reflect this properly and doesn't distinguish this as well. C++ is an _imperative language_ (though it picks up some functional techniques). In imperative languages, assignment and equality are distinct. `i = i + 1;` is mathematical non-sense. (Infinity and -Infinity are the only "numbers" I know which may resolve this equation.) But, this is a very usual statement in imperative languages, as variables represent storage (but not symbolic in-variants) and the actual meaning is `iNew = iOld + 1`. ;-)

Comment: Btw. I wonder that your compiler didn't complain about your `operator=()`. I'm not sure whether the standard requires diagnostics but I'm sure that I get such in my aged VS2013. (Something with "not all code paths return a value" or similar.) It might be a matter of enabled warnings. If so, you should enable more. They might appear annoying at the first glance but, actually, they are a real help to keep code running as expected when it grows over time. (There's still enough opportunity for U.B. in the language where the compiler is not able to warn about...) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff that was actually very informative, thank you!  looking back at it now I can see how its obviously the assignment operator and the difference between the two, thank you.  I am curious though, why does it need to ```return *this```? is it because it is returning a whole binary tree(which I'm assuming is the empty tree that I am copying the values into)?

Comment: In C++ (as well as in C), the assignment is not a statement (like in other "comparable" languages like e.g. Pascal or BASIC) but an operator which allows to use it in expressions. That enables e.g. chaining (e.g. `a = b = c;`) as well as any other usage as LValue (e.g. `(tree = otherTree).print();`). So, it's usually expected that an assignment operator returns a reference to its left hand side. (The assignment operator is one of the few right-associative operators. So, `a = b = c;` is resolved as `a = (b = c);` where `(b = c)` returns the reference to `b` which is then assigned to `a`.)